# Using glossaries to create an abbreviation list

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm trying to use the `glossaries` package to create an abbreviation list.

I'm writing a book like document using `\chapters`.

Just before the main body, I have

```
\usepackage[nopostdot]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\loadglsentries{AbbreviatureList/AbbreviatureList}

\begin{document}

\gls{loremipsum}

 \appendix

 \chapter{Abbreviations}
 \printglossary[style=list]

\end{document}
```

In the current working directory, there's a folder called "AbbreviatureList" and inside, there's a file"AbbreviatureList.tex" with the following entry

```
\newglossaryentry{loremipsum}{name={lorem ipsum},
description={dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris.}}
```

My abbreviation page doesn't show anything. I've even tried changing the location of the `printglossary` command, but the result was the same.

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question. Did you actually "use" the abbriaviation somewhere in your text with `\gls` or a similar command?

Comment: @leandriis I'll prepare it a few moments. Meanwhile, to answer your question, yes I used \gls{loremipsum}

Comment: @leandriis I've just added the MWE

Comment: Did you already run `makeglossaries` on your .tex file? Adding `automake` to the `glossaries` options might also help.

Comment: @leandriis I'm not sure I follow you... You're asking if in "AbbreviationList.tex" I run \makeglossaries? I only use \makeglossaries just below the \usepackage command

Comment: The `\makeglossaries` command only belong in your actual document. Just as you have to run`biber` on the document to get the references right when using `biblatex`, you will have to run  an external progam on your file to get the glossary/list of abbreviations. Depending on your needs, there are different programs available. The ["Beginner's giude" of `glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) contains an overview over the available methods.